# Django Widget SelectMultiple

Tags: django, select, widget, admin

I am unable to use the widget selectMultiple use by django admin. Form.html on my template, only the "submit" button is displayed. If anyone can help me :) here is my code.

## models.py

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    sub_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject=models.ManyToManyField(Subjects)
```

## forms.py

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Student
        subject=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Subjects.objects.all())


class subAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subjects
```

## views.py

```
def addSub(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = subAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event, created = Subjects.objects.get_or_create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/subject/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('accueil/accueil.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = subAddForm()
        return render(request, 'accueil/accueil.html', {'form': form})

def form(request):
    stud_form=StudentForm()
    if request.POST:
        stud_form=StudentForm(request.POST)
        stud_form.save()
        return render_to_response("success.html")
    else:
        return render_to_response("test/form.html",{' stud_form': stud_form})


def subject(request):
    subject = Subjects.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'test/subject.html', {'subject': subject})
```

## mon template form.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}

        <script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX}}js/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX}}js/getElementsBySelector.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX}}js/actions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX}}js/SelectBox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX}}js/SelectFilter2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jsi18n.js"></script>
    <div>
            <div id="overview">
    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Select Multiple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565200/django-select-multiple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want template for both student and topic, then in your student function of views.py , ' stud_form' should be 'form' without the **space**

Comment: because ' stud_form' was not used in your template. your template use {{ form.as_p }} instead of {{ stud_form.as_p }}.

Comment: and ' stud_form' has a space at the beginning. It's very dangerous. use 'stud_form'

Comment: Yes, i have changed the "stud_form" to "form" but it doesn't work ^^

Comment: Ho yes, i didn't see the "space" at the beginning of "stud_form" (now it's "form"). I have something now tks you :) it's so much better, but  it's not like the django admin, i mean i don't have two select list with options with remove and add actions, just a select list to choose the subject ^^

Comment: check on this http://grokbase.com/t/gg/django-users/131z9ryq10/problem-with-filteredselectmultiple-widget

Comment: Thank you, now it's work :)
And I found something to add:
 
jQuery.each($("select[multiple]"), function () {  
 // "Locations" can be any label you want  
 SelectFilter.init(this.id, "Locations", 0, "/media/");  
});

Add this script in the form.html

Comment: you're welcome. would you mind adopting my answer :)